# How do I replace a div after dropdown selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery

All I need is to replace the form with `class="simple_form calculation"` when the jQuery dropdown has been selected. Here is my jQuery.

Can I use a `.replaceAll` for this?

```
$("#role_selector_for_questions").change(function(e) {
   var $dropdown = $(this);
   $.get('/calculations/role/' + $dropdown.val(), function(data) {
      $dropdown.after(data);
   });
});
```

Comment: Please post a complete code example please.

Comment: What do you mean by replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to change the class of a form element

if so you can use [jQuery .removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) to remove current class and [jQuery .addClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) to add new class.

```
$("#role_selector_for_questions").change(function(e) {
  var $dropdown = $(this);

  $('yourformid').removeClass('old_form_class');
  $('yourformid').addClass('simple_form calculation');

  $.get('/calculations/role/' + $dropdown.val(), function(data) {
       $dropdown.after(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: This worked great... I actually went with a .remove(); and that did exactly what was needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where your 'form' element is defined, but changing a class on the form is as simple as using removeClass() and addClass().

```js
$('#formToAddClass').removeClass('current_class').addClass('simple_form calculation');
```

BTW, looks like two classes are being added here - 'simple_form' and 'calculation'. Class names do not contain spaces.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#role_selector_for_questions").change(function(e) {
  var $dropdown = $(this);
  $.get('/calculations/role/' + $dropdown.val(), function(data) {
       $("#role_selector_for_questison").replaceWith( "<div></div>" );
  });
});
```